# Cordova - Alter Push Notifications on the device

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, notifications, push

I have Push Plugin enabled on my device using [this - I suppose almost standard - plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push). I can change the plugin, however, if your solutions involve another one.

What I want to do is receive certain notifications via push (Google GCM mostly for now) and then alter them on the device before showing them (mainly translation for the specific locale).

I assumed something like using a push notification plugin to receive the notifications (but not show them!) and then passing them to a local notification plugin to show the altered notification would be the solution. But all push plugins I see automatically show the notification.

Is there any way around that or something else entirely to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement silent push notifications, in which case no notification is displayed.

Comment: Through which plugin?

Comment: "Silent" is a feature of the notification service (APNS, GCM, etc.) not plugin specific.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks